# Insert Stored Procedure and other variables into a temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure and 3 variables. I need to insert them all on the same line in a temp table. Is this possible? I tried

```
INSERT INTO #Temp (@Ad, @B, @C, @SPInt) 
    SELECT 
        @Ad, @B, @C, EXEC sp_XYZ @A, @B, @C
```

But this does not work.

Comment: It's unclear from your question if `sp_XYZ` produces rows and you want those in `#temp`, or if you're simply trying to capture the return value (which is much simpler: `EXEC @SPInt = sp_XYZ @A, @B, @C` followed by the `INSERT`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simplest approach is to modify the stored procedure to return the input arguments along with everything else.

Absent that, you need to store the output results somewhere and then insert into `#Temp`.  Here is one way:

```
create table #temp_exec (. . .);
insert into #temp_exec ( . . . )
    exec sp_xyz @A, @B, @C;

insert into #temp (a, b, c, . . . )
    select @A, @B, @C, . . .
    from #temp_exec;
```

If `#temp` starts out as empty, then you don't need another table:

```
insert into #temp ( . . . )
    exec sp_xyz @A, @B, @C;

update #temp
    set a = @A, b = @b, c = @c;
```

Comment: How did I not think of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot do this all in one statement.

You can do the INSERT..EXEC in one statement, and then add the variables in an UPDATE statement.   But you have to use two different statements to do this.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That will be an issue since the SP returns an int. I supposed I will just to update MAX(row_number), this is going to greatly increase my execution time :(.